# How do I mount a Z Drive (from Windows) into Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, windows

I'm really new to Linux. I have bioinformatics data on a Z drive in Windows. The software that I need to run my data is in Linux. How do I mount the Z Drive so I can access the data in Ubuntu? Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: The "Z Drive" means nothing to Ubuntu.  Was the Z Drive a network share?  An external disk?  We need more information.  (if you don't know this information, then you need to find out because we won't be able to assist without that information)

Comment: Usually Z drive really is a *some_share* on *some_server* working over SMB/CIFS protocol. That is in Nautilus (Files, file-manager) you can write `smb://some_server/some_share` in Location bar to get this share working.

Comment: Z drive was an external hard drive.